# jquery autocomplete is displaying & as &amp

Tags: jquery

Text in Db field - Test & Test

Displayed in Jquery Auto complete  - Test &amp Test

```
Jquery Code:
$(function(){
    $("#search_client_input").autocomplete({
      source: url+"get_alike_clients",
      minLength: 1
    });
  });
```

PHP Code (to get data from DB and return to Jquery):

```
public function fetch_alike_clients($clients)
    {
        $this->db->select('nameClient');
        $this->db->like('UPPER(nameClient)', strtoupper($clients));
        $query = $this->db->get('client_data');
        $clients_data_set = array();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $clients_data_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['nameClient']));
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($clients_data_set);
    }
```

Not sure how to fix this issue as it is appearing in all names which have & in its name.

Comment: What do you get in return from the server?

Comment: @Dekel added the PHP code to get the data

Comment: You are using the [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) function, which converts `&` to `&amp;`, and you are asking why your code has `amp;` instead of `&` ? :)